# Creating static link for assets in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, game-engine

I need to create a active url or link that will display the assets in my Application.

So for example a dog.png
Should be found in something like:
localhost:3000/static/media/dog.png

In React, for image files, if I do

```
import cat_png from '../../game_book/images/cat.png';
```

cat_png will actually hold the following values which works for me:

```
http://localhost:3000/static/media/cat.35853d78.png
```

Eventhough javascript changed cat.png to cat.35853d78.png that is fine in my case because I have a static URL to that asset...(What do you call this kind of link?  Is it called a asset link?)...

However for my json files if I do:

```
import animals_json from '../../game_book/images/animals.json';
```

animal_json will actually contain the contents of the json file 
e.g.

```
{frames: {…}, meta: {…}}
```

and does not give me a active URL where the contents of the json file can be displayed.

What I would like instead is a link like:

```
http://localhost:3000/static/media/animals.json
```

That will display the contents of my file

I am working through a book on javascript game programming and the sample code loads the assets though those active URL links for the assets....

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Webpack 4 provides native handling of json files**. Which means by default imports of json files will be handled by webpack and we will always get json as javascript object when we try to import.

Refer Webpack documentation https://webpack.js.org/concepts/ under Loaders section -

> Out of the box, webpack only understands JavaScript and JSON files.

So if you want to override this behaviour and import json as a URL you will have to add an additional loader which can handle json files and modify the default behaviour.

One such is url-loader. Add below lines in your webpack.config.js -

```
       {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: false,
            publicPath: 'assets'
          },
          type:'javascript/auto'
        }
```

This will load all the json files as urls.

Comment: Hi, I'm using React JS.  Does React use Webpack by default?  Where do I find the webpack.config.js in a React App?

Comment: Hi I have added it to the webpack.config.dev.js file but I am getting an error: Error in ./src/components/layout/Landing.js
Module not found: 'url-loader' in /Users/bliss/Documents/Coder/MERN/javascript_game_book/client/src/components/layout

 @ ./src/components/layout/Landing.js 34:15-61

Comment: btw I have installed url-loader on the client side of the React App

Comment: Are you still seeing that 'Module not found' error even after installing 'url-loader'?

Comment: Yes I have installed url-loader via npm install url-loader --save-dev in the client folder

Comment: Do you think your code will work with Craco ? https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#installation